# Need to reboot Mac after running pfctl -e

Tags: macos

I'm trying to set up my firewall on my Mac.  I've been trying to use `pf` for this and some how I've ended up in a situation when I go through the following steps, I get locked out of my remote Mac and I need to reboot it.

1. `sudo pfctl -d`
2. `sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf`
3. `sudo pfctl -e`

Because I'm new with `pf`, I am not sure how to troubleshoot this.  So, I'm looking for some guidance on how to troubleshoot and/or any leads on what might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that I was actually blocking myself out (ugh).  Rookie mistake.  I was building a `pf table` based on a text file where I was keeping a list of bad IPs.  This file was being maintained by parsing through my `/var/log/system.log` file and finding failed authentications.  Somehow, I picked up the machine's IP address and put that into the "bad IP" file.

Luckily, `pf` wasn't being enabled upon booting up the machine.  So, when I would enable pf (`sudo pfctl -e`) and get locked out, I could remotely reboot the machine (thanks to Macminicolo.net's reboot functionality) and get access to the machine.

The good news is that I now know a lot more about `pfctl` and working with it on a Mac.